# How to open script inside Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

I have shortcut which under the hood performs something like that:

> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "powershell D:\ssh.ps1"

it executes `ssh.ps1` script which inside opens SSH to `ssh user@$ip` where `$ip` comes from variable

but it executes inside `cmd`, meanwhile I'd want to start it inside `Windows Terminal` - how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Window Terminal installed to the default location, it will be located here where USERNAME is your username:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe`

Create your shortcut with the starting location set to something like this:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File D:\ssh.ps1`

Comment: thanks, it worked! I previously used path like that: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.0.1401.0_x64__8w...d8bbwe`